# Format Time in Visual Studio Report Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting, rdlc

I have a time field in SQL server that I am trying to display on a rdlc report in visual studio.  I would like it to be in HH:mm format but it continues to display as HH:mm:ss.  The seconds portion is always zero and I don't want it shown.  I thought this would be an easy format fix but none of my expressions seem to work.

```
Format(Fields!my_time.Value,"HH:mm")
Left(Fields!my_time.Value,5).ToString()    
Hour(Fields!my_time.Value) + ":" + Minute(Fields!my_time.Value)
```

I've never used the report features in visual studio before so I'm hoping I'm missing something easy. Is there someplace other than the format property I should be trying these?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Fields!my_time is a DateTime field, you can do this:

1. Change the value of the control where this data is displayed to just use Fields!my_time.Value rather than an expression
2. Right-click the control and select Text Box Properties
3. Select Number, then Time in the Category list, then the time format you wish to use

This may give you better results than attempting to format through an expression.